# Is there a C function that returns the second, third, etc. instance an int value occurs?

Tags: c, search

I have implemented code that imports data from a file containing 5 different values, one of them being Time. I have converted the time given in the format Hour.Minute.Second.Millisecond into just Milliseconds.

With this data I created a function `Find` that finds the data for a given time. This is where the problem arises, since there are multiple days of data here, and the time will repeat multiple times. Is there a function in the C library that returns all instances of a value? Ex.`arr =[2,3,4,1,2,]` I want it to tell me when the second 2 appears, returning `4`.

**Edit:** For better clarity

These are the functions

```
void Find(SortedLinkedList *list,int target,int date, char *search) {
    if(strcmp(search, "Time") == 0){
      Sate *found = findTime(list, target,date);
      printf("The Node with time:%d\n Is from the date:%d\n Contains the following:",found->Time,found->Date);
      printf("RMag:%6.3f ", found->rmag);
        printf("NSmag:%6.3f ", found->NSmag);
        printf("azmag:%6.3f ", found->azmag);
        printf("avgmag:%6.3f \n", found->avgmag);
    }

}

Sate *findTime(SortedLinkedList *list, int target,int date){
    Node *current = list->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < (list->size)+1 && current != NULL; i++) {
        if(current->data->Time == target && current->data->Date == date)
         return current->data;
    else{
      current = current->next;

    }
    }

}
```

Right now for it to work I implemented a `date` insert to differentiate between the times but I'm wondering if it can be done without it.

Comment: Are you asking how to search for a value in an array?

Comment: no there is not

Comment: C doesn't support such function. The arrays first index is 0, not 1.

Comment: Are you expecting each posisble value of milliseconds to repeat each day? It seems that in your situation you just want to detect the start of a new day as the only situation in which the total of millisecond decrease, while they otherwise always increase.

Comment: "With this data I created a function `Find` that finds the data for a certain time given, " --> posting that code would improve this question's value and clarity.

Comment: Rather than letting your data contain ambiguously duplicated times, it seems to me it would be much better to structure your data so that all times are unambiguous.  If you can't change the input format, you could at least reconstruct a `day` value by detecting when the hour wraps from 23 back to 0.

Comment: Not exactly I'm asking if there is a function in C that goes through the array and tell you the second time it appears or third and so on. Yes the milliseconds do repeat every day since the data was collected every minute daily.

Comment: No you&#39;re have to write a function that does that. Look at hashing as a possible good and fast solution.

Comment: There will be such a function as soon as you write it.

Answer (score 2):

There's not any kind of a iterate over a collection type of function in the Standard C library other than something like `strtok()` which will iterate over a text string using the provided token identification pattern.

There is the `bsearch()` function however that does a search through a sorted list of items and is not really what you want either.

It sounds like you want something like the following. This demonstrates an instantiation of an algorithm however I am not sure what the time points data looks like so that is something you will need to provide.

```
typedef unsigned long long  TimePoint;     // made up time data item

typedef  struct {
    int            bFound;
    unsigned long  ulCurOffset; // array position where item found if bFound is true.
    unsigned long  ulOffset;    // next array position to test
    unsigned long  ulCount;     // count of times found
} IteratorThing;

IteratorThing IterateFunc (IteratorThing x, TimePoint *array, size_t len, TimePoint search)
{
    x.bFound = 0;    // assume we didn't find one.
    // resuming from the current place in the array, search until we
    // find a match or we reach the end of the array.
    for ( ; x.ulOffset < len; x.ulOffset++) {
        // this is a simple comparison for equality which may need to be
        // more complex for your specific application.
        if (array[x.ulOffset] == search) {
            // we have found a match so lets update counts, etc.
            x.ulCount++;     // count of this search item found.
            x.bFound = 1;    // indicate we found one.
            x.ulCurOffset = x.ulOffset;   // remember where we found it.
            x.ulOffset++;    // point to the next array item to look at
            break;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

This would be used as in:

```
void main_xfun(void)
{
    TimePoint  array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0 };
    TimePoint  search = 2;
    size_t     len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    {
        IteratorThing x = { 0 };  // define and initialize our iterator
        while ((x = IterateFunc(x, array, len, search)).bFound) {
            // do what is needed when we find a time value
            // array offset to the item is x.ulCurOffset
            // current count of times found is in x.ulCount;
            printf("   found item %d at offset %d count is %d\n", (long)array[x.ulCurOffset], x.ulCurOffset, x.ulCount);
        }
        printf(" item %d found %d time\n", (long)search, x.ulCount);
    }

    {
        IteratorThing x = { 0 };  // define and initialize our iterator
        search = 25;
        while ((x = IterateFunc(x, array, len, search)).bFound) {
            // do what is needed when we find a time value
            // array offset to the item is x.ulCurOffset
            // current count of times found is in x.ulCount;
            printf("   found item %d at offset %d count is %d\n", (long)array[x.ulCurOffset], x.ulCurOffset, x.ulCount);
        }
        printf(" item %d found %d time\n", (long)search, x.ulCount);
    }
}
```

produces output of

```
    found item 2 at offset 1 count is 1
    found item 2 at offset 3 count is 2
 item 2 found 2 time
 item 25 found 0 time
```

To restart the search from the beginning just initialize the iterator struct to all zeros again.

What would be really interesting is to provide a pointer to a comparison function in the interface of the function `IterateFunc()` which would be called to do the comparisons. This would be along the lines of the `bsearch()` function which requires a pointer to a comparison function but then that is probably overkill for your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this hypothetical function to work for either an array of integers or for your time indexed structures, you will probably need to write a generic function.

If POSIX functions are available to you, you can use [`lfind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lsearch.html) as a starting point for such a generic function.

> The `lsearch()` function shall linearly search the table and return a pointer into the table for the matching entry. If the entry does not occur, it shall be added at the end of the table. ...
>
> The `lfind()` function shall be equivalent to `lsearch()`, except that if the entry is not found, it is not added to the table. Instead, a null pointer is returned.

Since `lfind()` will return the first instance, you need to re-invoke `lfind()` again past the given instance to find the second instance.

```
void * lfind_Nth (const void *key, const void *base, size_t *nelp,
   size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *),
   int N)
{
    const char (*array)[width] = base;
    char (*p)[width] = NULL;
    size_t n = *nelp;

    while (N-- > 0) {
        p = n ? lfind(key, array, &n, width, compar) : NULL;
        if (p == NULL) break;
        n -= (p + 1) - array;
        array = p + 1;
    }

    return p;
}
```

For your integer array example:

```
int compar_int (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(const int *)a != *(const int *)b;
}

int where_Nth_int(int key, int *arr, size_t nelm, int N) {
    int *w = lfind_Nth(&key, arr, &nelm, sizeof(*arr),
                       compar_int, N);
    return w ? w - arr : -1;
}

int main (void) {
    int arr[] = {2,3,4,1,2,};
    int nelm = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    printf("Second 2 @ %d\n", where_Nth_int(2, arr, nelm, 2));
}
```

Comment: `lfind` and `lsearch` are not standard C functions. They're defined by POSIX.

Comment: I suspect that a function that performs the required task directly would be simpler than one that uses `lfind`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Possibly, but note the lack of a "complete" implementation was intentional.